# My xamarin app shows my code in release mode

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm a beginner in Xamarin and I just create a simple android app in Xamarin by preprocessed razor template.

But after debugging or after releasing and installing the app on my phone, if I tap on the screen a white page it showed, and in another phone my code were shown on the phone.

What can I do to solve this problem?
This is my code:

```
<div class="row" style="padding:5px">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <a href="file:///android_asset/Ethicshtml.cshtml" class="navbar-brand">Home</a>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                </div>
                <ul class="collapse nav navbar-nav" id="mainNavBar">
                    <li><a href="file:///android_asset/Professional.cshtml">Profesional</a></li>
                    <li><a href="file:///android_asset/Moral.cshtml">Moral</a></li>
                    <li><a href="file:///android_asset/Security.cshtml">Security</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"></ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: Showing the code when accrued that I tap on the navbar. I used navbar class in HTML code. Then I can't access other pages.

Comment: “I just create a simple android app in Xamarin by preprocessed razor template” is not something trivial that any reader can understand. If you don't plan to share more information, you probably should not even post such a question.

Comment: I mean just I copied my HTML codes in preprocessed razor template item by right click on Asset in my project. I thought it is clear to all who are not beginner

Comment: “Preprocessed Razor Template” is listed under Advanced section, which by itself shows whether it is suitable for beginners. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/razor_html_templates/ Of course, there is a complete sample listed on the page, so you can review that to learn more.

Comment: Merely saying "it is not about ... it is about" is not the way of describing a problem or asking a question. You have to provide enough information so any other can easily reproduce it, which so far you failed completely. Not easy for a beginner of Stack Overflow, but you must learn that before receiving good answers.

Comment: I should change href in <a> with razor object?